# Two list view in android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I am new to android development. I have two listview in one xml file. I have placed two list view under relative layout and apply scroll view to whole relative layout. But here problem is that when i try to scroll list view my whole page gets scroll. Any suggestion to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your xml please?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ListView` within `ScrollView` wil not work properly in android. If you want to have multiple `ListView` may be you can try Jeff Sahrkey adapter -

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Work in xml file    
<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <ListView   android:id="@+id/list1" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
        <ListView   android:id="@+id/list2" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        </ListView>
```

```
// Now work in java file
 public class yourActivity extends Activity {
 private ListView listv1 = null;
 private ListView listv2 = null;
 private String string1[] = {"apple","card", "man"};
 private String string2[] = {"ball", "soccer", "tiger"};

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //your listview
listv1 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list1);
listv2 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list2);

listv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, string1));
listv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, string2));

   } 

 }
```